# Python Enums across Modules

Tags: python, module, enums

Why can in Python 3 enum equality not be checked correctly across module boundaries if the enum has been defined in the main module? Here is an example:

moduleA.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import moduleB
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    # def __eq__(self,other):
    #     assert isinstance(other,self.__class__)
    #     return self.value == other.value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    myVar = MyEnum.B
    moduleB.doStuff(myVar)
```

moduleB.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import moduleA

def doStuff(aVariable):
    bVariable = moduleA.MyEnum.B
    assert aVariable == bVariable
```

Calling "*./moduleA.py*" on the command line yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./moduleA.py", line 17, in <module>
    moduleB.doStuff(myVar)
  File "/home/ruedi/Dropbox/Reps/stuffed/sosy/testing/moduleB.py", line 7, in doStuff
    assert aVariable == bVariable
AssertionError
```

Uncommenting the custom equality operator in the enum leads to an assertion failure there. I've found that the class module is not the same in both cases, as it is "__main__" in one case.

What is the most "Pythonic way" to fix this problem (other than moving the enum to its own module)?

**EDIT:** Switching to "aVariable is bVariable" does not work either:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./moduleA.py", line 17, in <module>
    moduleB.doStuff(myVar)
  File "/home/ruedi/Dropbox/Reps/stuffed/sosy/testing/moduleB.py", line 7, in doStuff
    assert aVariable is bVariable
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as Python is concerned, you have **three** modules here:

- `__main__`
- `moduleA`
- `moduleB`

The file you run from the command line, the main entry point, is always stored as the `__main__` module. If you import `moduleA` anywhere in the code, Python sees that as separate from the `__main__` module and creates instead a new module object. You thus have *two* separate `MyEnum` classes:

- `__main__.MyEnum`
- `moduleA.MyEnum`

Their members are distinct and thus cannot be equal.

Your test passes if instead of using `import moduleA` you used `import __main__ as moduleA`, or used a *separate* script file to drive the test; that separate file would become `__main__`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# test.py, separate from moduleA.py and moduleB.py

import moduleA    
import moduleB

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myVar = moduleA.MyEnum.B
    moduleB.doStuff(myVar)
```

Another workaround would be to tell Python that `__main__` and `moduleA` are the same thing; *before* importing `moduleA` (or `moduleB`, which imports `moduleA`) you can add another entry to `sys.modules`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.modules['moduleA'] = sys.modules['__main__']

import moduleB
```

I'd not consider this very Pythonic.

Comment: Is there a good reason why it works that way, why it makes the distinction between `__main__` and `moduleA`? Wouldn't you expect them to be the same?

Comment: @TankorSmash: they are separate because you need a way to distinguish between the main entry point (the script) and modules you import. This is why `if __name__ == '__main__':` works in the first place.